# Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.for Collection of DTO

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I was making an API for saving a model where it has one to many relationship with another model. When I applying automapping in it. it is giving me following error:

```
    CreateContestDto -> Contest
    tritronAPI.DTOs.CreateContestDto -> tritronAPI.Model.Contest

    Type Map configuration:
    CreateContestDto -> Contest
    tritronAPI.DTOs.CreateContestDto -> tritronAPI.Model.Contest

    Destination Member:
    Problems
    ---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map 
    configuration or unsupported mapping.

    Mapping types:
    ProblemDto -> Problem
    tritronAPI.DTOs.ProblemDto -> tritronAPI.Model.Problem
    at lambda_method(Closure , ProblemDto , Problem , ResolutionContext )
```

My models are: Contest and Problem a contest contain many problems:

```
    public class Contest
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Problem> Problems { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ContestProgrammingLanguage> 
        ContestProgrammingLanguages { get; set; }
    }


    public class Problem
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string ProblemName { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("User")]
        public string ProblemAuthorId { get; set; }
        public virtual User ProblemAuthor { get; set; }
        public string AuthorName { get; set; }
        //public virtual List<Resources> Resourceses { get; set; }
        public string ProblemDescription { get; set; }
        public bool IsPublished { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Submission> Submissions { get; set; }
        public string Tags { get; set; }
        //public Guid Contest_Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Contest Contest { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Contest")]
        public int? Contest_Id { get; set; }
        public short Score { get; set; }

        //Timelimit in miliseconds
        public int TimeLimit { get; set; }

        //MemoryLimit in bytes
        public int MemoryLimit { get; set; }

        //More than source code limit is not allowed
        public int? SourceCodeLimit { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TestFile> TestFiles { get; set; } = new 
        List<TestFile>();
    }


    public class CreateContestDto
    {
        public CreateContestDto()
        {
            this.Problems = new HashSet<ProblemDto>();
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
        public string BackgroundImage { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ProblemDto> Problems { get; set; }
    }


    public class ProblemDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ProblemName { get; set; }
    }
```

mapping profile:

```
    CreateMap<CreateContestDto, Contest>().ForMember(
    dest => dest.Problems , opt => opt.MapFrom(src => 
    src.Problems));
```

controller code:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddContest([FromBody] 
    CreateContestDto contest)
    {
        var con = _mapper.Map<Contest>(contest);
        this._uow.ContestRepository.Add(con);
        return Ok();
    }
```

I have already tried with reversemap selecting new id in mapping profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to add mappings for `ProblemDTO` to `Problem`:

```
CreateMap<CreateContestDto, Contest>();

CreateMap<ProblemDto, Problem>();
```

Comment: The MapFrom is not needed.